# Flutter: Circular border shows unwanted outline

Tags: flutter

While developing a chat bubble like notifier UI, I'm getting this issue of unwanted outline on the circle shape.

```
 Stack(
   overflow: Overflow.visible,
   children: <Widget>[
         Positioned(
             child: Image.asset(
                      "assets/v2/small/messenger-icon.png",
                      width: 28,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
         )),
         Positioned(
             top: -2,
             right: -2,
             child: Container(
                       width: 12,
                       height: 12,
                       decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: MyColors.accentColor,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                              border: Border.all(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  width: 1,
                                  style: BorderStyle.solid)),
                        ),
              )
   ],
)
```

[image]

Everything works fine but there is an unwanted MyColors.accentColor circular line over the white outline.

Comment: do you mean the white border?

Comment: With this code, I am not able to reproduce this issue, Can you try this code at your end and check, if it works please attach messenger-icon as well

Comment: there is a pinkAccent colored circle. then there is a white outline around the circle. which is my requirement. But there is an extra pinkAccent outline over the white area in the image.

Comment: This can be achieved in another way by creating two circles, first one white with a radius say 12, then another one with radius 11 and color as accentColor both having the same center. 
But I was just wondering how the solution I added in the code is showing this behavior.

Comment: @jitsm555 yes it is not visible with the sizes in the question. So for anyone trying to reproduce this- Change the width and height of `Container` to 120, `borderRadius` to 80 and border width to 5 and it is then visible. It is a very thin border outside of the white border. It is almost invisible. And in small sizes, completely invisible.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the border itself is an overlay above container's decoration.
A possible workaround for this is to use 2 containers.
The top one with the border and the bottom one with background.

```
Positioned(
                top: -2,
                right: -2,
                child: Container(
                  width: 12,
                  height: 12,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      width: 1,
                      style: BorderStyle.solid,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.purpleAccent,
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]Two containers with 1px difference in size is a solution

```
Stack(
    overflow: Overflow.visible,
    children: <Widget>[
      Positioned(
          child: Image.asset(
        "assets/mes1.png",
        width: 280,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      )),
      Positioned(
        top: -2,
        right: -2,
        child: Container(
          width: 121,
          height: 121,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(121),
              border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.white, width: 1, style: BorderStyle.solid)),
          child: Container(
            width: 120,
            height: 120,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.deepOrange,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(120),
                border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.deepOrange,
                    width: 1,
                    style: BorderStyle.solid)),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  )
```